# How to Recreate the Android Facebook app's view swiping UX?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, scroll

I'm looking to make something exactly like Facebook's Android app's UX for swiping between News Feed, Friend Requests, Messages, and Notifications.  You should be able to "peek" at the next view by panning to the right of left, and it should snap to the next page when released if some threshold has been passed or when swiped.

Every scroll snap solution I've seen only snaps after the scrolling stops, whereas I only ever want to scroll one page at a time.

EDIT: Here's what I have so far.  It seems to work fine when emulating an Android device in Google Chrome, but doesn't work when I run it on my Galaxy S4 running 4.4.2.  Looking into it a bit more, it looks like touchcancel is being fired right after the first touchmove event which seems like a bug.  Is there any way to get around this?

```
var width = parseInt($(document.body).width());
var panThreshold = 0.15;
var currentViewPage = 0;

$('.listContent').on('touchstart', function(e) {
  console.log("touchstart");
  currentViewPage = Math.round(this.scrollLeft / width);
});

$('.listContent').on('touchend', function(e) {
  console.log("touchend");
  var delta = currentViewPage * width - this.scrollLeft;

  if (Math.abs(delta) > width * panThreshold) {
    if (delta < 0) {
      currentViewPage++;
    } else {
      currentViewPage--;
    }
  }

  $(this).animate({
    scrollLeft: currentViewPage * width
  }, 100);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone wants to do this in the future, the only way I found to actually do this was to manually control all touch events and then re-implement the normally-native vertical scrolling.

It might not be the prettiest, but here's a fiddle to what I ended up doing (edited to use mouse events instead of touch events): http://jsfiddle.net/xtwzcjhL/

```
$(function () {
    var width = parseInt($(document.body).width());
    var panThreshold = 0.15;
    var currentViewPage = 0;
    var start; // Screen position of touchstart event
    var isHorizontalScroll = false; // Locks the scrolling as horizontal
    var target; // Target of the first touch event
    var isFirst; // Is the first touchmove event
    var beginScrollTop; // Beginning scrollTop of ul
    var atanFactor = 0.6; // atan(0.6) = ~31 degrees (or less) from horizontal to be considered a horizontal scroll
    var isMove = false;

    $('body').on('mousedown', '.listContent', function (e) {
        isMove = true;
        isFirst = true;
        isHorizontalScroll = false;
        target = $(this);
        currentViewPage = Math.round(target.scrollLeft() / width);
        beginScrollTop = target.closest('ul').scrollTop();
        start = {
            x: e.originalEvent.screenX,
            y: e.originalEvent.screenY
        }
    }).on('mousemove', '.listContent', function (e) {
        if (!isMove) {
            return false;
        }

        e.preventDefault();

        var delta = {
            x: start.x - e.originalEvent.screenX,
            y: start.y - e.originalEvent.screenY
        }

        // If already horizontally scrolling or the first touchmove is within the atanFactor, horizontally scroll, otherwise it's a vertical scroll of the ul
        if (isHorizontalScroll || (isFirst && Math.abs(delta.x * atanFactor) > Math.abs(delta.y))) {
            isHorizontalScroll = true;
            target.scrollLeft(currentViewPage * width + delta.x);
        } else {
            target.closest('ul').scrollTop(beginScrollTop + delta.y);
        }
        isFirst = false;
    }).on('mouseup mouseout', '.listContent', function (e) {
        isMove = false;
        isFirst = false;

        if (isHorizontalScroll) {
            var delta = currentViewPage * width - target.scrollLeft();

            if (Math.abs(delta) > width * panThreshold) {
                if (delta < 0) {
                    currentViewPage++;
                } else {
                    currentViewPage--;
                }
            }

            $(this).animate({
                scrollLeft: currentViewPage * width
            }, 100);
        }
    });
});
```